# M2 - Previous & Next product from category

Tags: magento2, sorting

I have this code below to show the Previous & Next buttons on the product detail page, but the next en previous product are based on the position in the category.

How can this be modified so the original view will used like the way that they are shown in the category view, because I don't make use of the position numbering in Magento admin.

On the frontend it's also possible to change the sorting, is it possible to use that also for the next & previous buttons?

```
<?php 

    $productId = $block->getProduct()->getId(); 
    $cat_ids = $block->getProduct()->getCategoryIds();

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    $productt = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

    $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($cat_ids[0]);
    // print_r($category->getUrl());
    $category_product = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc');
    $category_product->addAttributeToFilter('status',1);
    $category_product->addAttributeToFilter('visibility',4);

    $cat_prod_ids = $category_product->getAllIds();

    $_pos = array_search($productId, $cat_prod_ids); // get position of current product
    $_next_pos = $_pos+1;
    $_prev_pos = $_pos-1;
    $keys = array_keys($cat_prod_ids);

    if(in_array($_next_pos, $keys)){
        $_next_prod = $product->load($cat_prod_ids[$_next_pos]);
    }
    if(in_array($_prev_pos, $keys)){
        $_prev_prod = $productt->load($cat_prod_ids[$_prev_pos]);   
    }

?>

<div class="previous_next">
    <?php if(in_array($_prev_pos, $keys)): ?>
        <a href="<?php print_r($_prev_prod->getProductUrl()); ?>"><span>PREVIOUS </span></a>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(in_array($_next_pos, $keys)): ?>
        <a href="<?php print_r($_next_prod->getProductUrl()); ?>"><span>NEXT </span></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Regards,

Comment: It's also not returning the correct SEO friendly url. Only the URL without Category in it.

Comment: do you want next previous according to the Sort order specify into category?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Yes, that's what I need if possible :)